# Heroku app R99 error after ps:scale web=1 command

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku, proc

I am getting R99 error on deploying the application. This is the log of the error.
013-09-11T03:59:59.474112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `:
java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war`
013-09-11T04:00:01.980799+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
013-09-11T04:00:09.677377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
led to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
013-09-11T04:00:09.677604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
013-09-11T04:00:01.992776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
ashed

Please tell me if I have to provide anything elsa

Comment: had the same issue a few days ago, what I did was running `heroku ps:scale web=0` and then run `heroku ps:scale web=2` (where 2 is the number of web workers you would like to use)

Comment: I am using heroku ps:scale web=1

Comment: alright, so did it work scaling it down to 0 and then to 1?

Comment: I tried that as well but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take port for web dyno from environment from procfile. Without which it showed the folowing error